# Userforms and List Boxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm having a little trouble setting up my list boxes.  I want my user form to have two list boxes (one for months (jan-dec), and one for years (two digits).  I know that you have to put the values separated by semicolons but I'm not sure where I type this.

Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Jan", 0
        .AddItem "Feb", 1
        .AddItem "Mar", 2
        'etc...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that didn't work it's still returning a blank listbox... Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code for your form? Also what name have you given the listbox controls?

Comment: I don't necessarily have a code I created a userform and within that a list box and attached your code in the list box... I tried to learn more about user forms but neither google nor Microsoft help have been much help... Any suggestions?

Comment: this looks like a good start...
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?threadid=131000